# URL Rewrite not working; debugger says it would

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have the following htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^uploads/(.*)$ https://testcontainer2.venta.one/uploads/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Has anyone an idea, why my rewrite is not working?
Even the Debugger from https://htaccess.madewithlove.be says, that my rule would apply.

[image: Debuger Example]

Comment: Please don't test your Rules on, online sites; they are not trust worthy; they wouldn't check exactly what you are looking for, please test your rules in apache server and share with us what are the exact issue you are facing.

Comment: I dont have a apache server to test; its a webspace from strato i can only access via ftp.

Comment: And "is not working" means what _exactly_ ?

Comment: Where are you putting the `.htaccess` file? Are you sure that `.htaccess` files are enabled on your server? The directive you posted (and testing) is an "external redirect", not a "URL rewrite" as you have stated in the title/tags?

Comment: File is placed in the Servers "Web Root"; as far as i can tell even the http to https rewrite works just the url filter seems to not apply

Comment: With the limited information in the question, this _should_ work. What is the response you are seeing? What actually happens? Is `/uploads/demopicture.png` served? (Assuming this exists.) Or are you seeing a 404? And what generates this response? "as far as i can tell even the http to https rewrite works" - That is a "redirect", not a "rewrite", but are you sure that something else is not redirecting HTTP to HTTPS (perhaps in your application logic)?

Comment: Yes, indeed file is served; since the other pages are plain html with a .php ending, there is no application logic; Could it be strato is restricting rewrites to external urls?

Comment: "Yes, indeed file is served" - please check the HTTP response headers. If "strato" have a front-end proxy for serving static assets (Nginx is commonly used for this to increase performance) then this will completely bypass your application server (Apache) and the redirect will not occur. Is your host using a front-end proxy? Try requesting a file that does not exist, eg. `/uploads/does-not-exist.png`.

Comment: I just gave them a call and they said, they would limit the htaccess options...

Another reason to change the hoster -_- thank you for your support though

Comment: "they would limit the htaccess options" - hmmm, what does that mean?

Comment: No rewrites except https rewrite  which can also be injected by their webinterface and file endings; Only Error Docs, Secure Directories, and IP deny/allowlist

Comment: "No rewrites except https rewrite" - That's just bizarre. But to clarify, these are "redirects", not "rewrites". If they were to _somehow_ (?!) block "rewrites" it would break the majority of websites (WordPress, Joomla, Drupal, etc.). What they might be doing is blocking _external_ redirects?! (Although that would be very underhanded.) Apache itself allows you to limit the directives that can be used in `.htaccess`, so it could block `RewriteRule` for instance, but it doesn't allow you to distinguish between "types" of `RewriteRule` directive. It's `RewriteRule` or nothing.

Comment: My guess is, their passing all the files thru some tool that just allows rewrites on an allowlist... Wordpress etc is installable via their panel so they might know what is necessary there

Comment: Did you try redirecting `/uploads/<something-that-does-not-exist>`?